# Extract image from input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrxnne9q/2/)

If you will look in console.log you will see the img will appear inside of input but I want to append  the image right after div.pic-box what can I do?

Here is a part of code..jS :

```
$(function() {
  $("input[type=file]").on("change", function(e) {
    var output = $("<img/>", {
      src: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
    });
    $(e.target).append("div.pic-box").html(output)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try append the element to target's parent:

```
$(e.target.parentNode).append("div.pic-box").html(output)
```

Comment: It's ok partial..the problem is ..I want to keep the input...but to put image right after the div with class 'pic-box'.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$(e.target).append("div.pic-box").html(output);
```

to

```
output.appendTo("div.pic-box");
```

That may match your expection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  $("input[type=file]").on("change", function(e) {
    var output = $("<img/>", {
      src: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
    });
    console.log(e.target);
    $(this).closest("div.pic-box").parent().children("img").remove();
    $(this).closest("div.pic-box").after(output);
    
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q9vfa9uc/)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the parent div and add your img after.

```
$(this).closest("div").after(output)
```

Please try below:

```js
  $("input[type=file]").on("change", function(e) {
    var output = $("<img/>", {
      src: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
    });
    console.log(e.target);
    $(this).closest("div").after(output)
  });
```

```css
.fileContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.fileContainer [type=file] {
  cursor: inherit;
  display: block;
  font-size: 999px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
  top: 0;
}

.pic-box {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-top: 3%;
}

.plus-box {
  color: red;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 30px;
}

.padding-box {
  padding-left: 5px !important;
  padding-right: 5px !important;
  padding-top: 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs-2" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-elements">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 fileContainer padding-box">
        <div class="pic-box">
          <div class="plus-box">xyz</div>
          <input type="file" accept="image/*">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 fileContainer padding-box">
        <div class="pic-box">
          <div class="plus-box">xyz</div>
          <input type="file" accept="image/*">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 fileContainer padding-box">
        <div class="pic-box">
          <div class="plus-box">xyz</div>
          <input type="file" accept="image/*">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 fileContainer padding-box">
        <div class="pic-box">
          <div class="plus-box">xyz</div>
          <input type="file" accept="image/*">
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```